# How to downgrade libdrm-intel1?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, downgrade

I know what my problem is and what must be done can be seen here:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768045

I must downgrade from 2.4.58 to 2.4.56. When I try via the following I get an error:

```
sudo dpkg -i libdrm-intel1-dbg_2.4.56-1_amd64.deb libdrm-intel1-dbg_2.4.56-1_i386.deb
```

Error:

```
(Reading database ... 177231 files and directories currently
installed.) Preparing to unpack libdrm-intel1-dbg_2.4.56-1_amd64.deb
... Unpacking libdrm-intel1-dbg:amd64 (2.4.56-1) over (2.4.56-1) ...
Preparing to unpack libdrm-intel1-dbg_2.4.56-1_i386.deb ... Unpacking
libdrm-intel1-dbg:i386 (2.4.56-1) over (2.4.56-1) ... dpkg: dependency
problems prevent configuration of libdrm-intel1-dbg:amd64: 
libdrm-intel1-dbg:amd64 depends on libdrm-intel1 (= 2.4.56-1);
however:   Version of libdrm-intel1:amd64 on system is
2.4.59+git20150125.0c5aaeef-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty.

dpkg: error processing package libdrm-intel1-dbg:amd64 (--install): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libdrm-intel1-dbg:i386: 
libdrm-intel1-dbg:i386 depends on libdrm-intel1 (= 2.4.56-1); however:
Version of libdrm-intel1:i386 on system is
2.4.59+git20150125.0c5aaeef-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty.

dpkg: error processing package libdrm-intel1-dbg:i386 (--install): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
while processing:  libdrm-intel1-dbg:amd64  libdrm-intel1-dbg:i386
```

How do I downgrade without screwing everything up?

Output from `apt-cache policy libdrm-intel1 libdrm-intel1-dbg`:

```
libdrm-intel1:   Installed:
2.4.59+git20150125.0c5aaeef-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty   Candidate: 2.4.59+git20150125.0c5aaeef-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty   Version table:  *** 2.4.59+git20150125.0c5aaeef-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.56-1~ubuntu1 0
        400 http://ftp.acc.umu.se/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.4.52-1 0
        400 http://ftp.acc.umu.se/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        400 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages libdrm-intel1-dbg:   Installed: 2.4.56-1   Candidate:
2.4.59+git20150125.0c5aaeef-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty   Version table:
     2.4.59+git20150125.0c5aaeef-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages  *** 2.4.56-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.56-1~ubuntu1 0
        400 http://ftp.acc.umu.se/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.4.52-1 0
        400 http://ftp.acc.umu.se/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        400 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libdrm-intel1 libdrm-intel1-dbg`? In my 14.04 system 2.4.56 is the highest version available...

Comment: @Salem Oh I must apologize, I am running xorg-edgers ppa. I do not know how to get back to 2.4.56 though :/

Comment: install & use ppa-purge. The ppa page tells you how - https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: @doug I do receive and error now while trying to install purge! Updated question with info!

Comment: @doug false alarm, fixed the install of ppa-purge via `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: @doug I unfortunately cannot purge, it would mean uninstalling far too much of my system (which is odd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to downgrade everything via the program synaptic.